# Check if user has logined under 10 minutes by unix timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check if a user has logined 10 minutes ago or not . I have used the following query and last_login is in unix timestamp . But the following code i made also shows the result if the user had logined 1 hour ago . How to check for user logined only 10 minutes ago or under 10 minutes .

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE last_login < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -600 ) 
AND user_id =  '4'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for any user who signed up in the last 10 minutes, you must use the "greater than" `>`. If you use "lower then" `<`, you get all user who signed up later than 10 minutes.  i.e. the user who signed up 1 hour ago, too.